Unusual but consistent variation in alternate sensor analog readings
I have designed some sensors that take readings of timber resistance between 2 screws with the idea to determine if the timber is getting wet from a leak. I have had a trial setup running with 6 sensors in some dry timber just to get some stable data. The resistance readings vary with temperature as documented in many studies about timber moisture measurement. Sensors 2, 4, and 6 have very little variation in the "stable data" while sensors 1,3,5  have lots of variation in the data. See the graph for the quartile spread of 10 days of data (1 rdg per hr so ~240 rdgs sample size/sensor) 
All the sensors are identical in design and use an op-amp and voltage divider to determine the resistance value. The sensors are connected to the analog inputs of an Arduino mega A0-A5. Each reading is actually an average of 2000 readings per sensor. See below for the analog reading and averaging code.
const int numReadings = 100;  //sample smoothing 1 cache
const int numReadings2 = 20;  //second smoothing cache
int readings[numReadings];    //array to store the readings from the analog input
int readIndex = 0;
unsigned long total[16];  // the running total
int average = 0;          // the average of first cache

int readings2[numReadings2];  // the readings from the analog input #2
int readIndex2 = 0;
unsigned long total2[16];                                                                     // the running total #2
int average2[16];                                                                             // averaged final output for each sensor[]
const int inputPin[16] = { 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69 };  //analog pin numbers

int dummyRead;  //when we take analog reading we take 2 readings and discard the first

void takeReadingMoisture() {
  delay(50);

  delay(2000);
  for (byte i = 0; i < 8; i++) {  //selects between sensor input pins i=inputPin

    total[i] = 0;
    total2[i] = 0;
    for (int thisReading = 0; thisReading < numReadings2; thisReading++) {  //fills buffer with zeros for next sensor
      readings2[thisReading] = 0;
    }
    for (int thisReading = 0; thisReading < numReadings; thisReading++) {  //fills buffer with zeros for next sensor
      readings[thisReading] = 0;
    }

    while (readIndex2 < numReadings2) {

      while (readIndex < numReadings) {

        total[i] = total[i] - readings[readIndex];  // subtract the last reading:
        dummyRead = analogRead(inputPin[i]); //take dummy reading to stabilise analog input
        delay(10);
        readings[readIndex] = analogRead(inputPin[i]);  // read from the sensor:
        total[i] = total[i] + readings[readIndex];      // add the reading to the total:

        delay(1);  // delay in between reads for stability
        readIndex++;
      }
      average = (total[i] / numReadings);
      readIndex = 0;

      total2[i] = total2[i] - readings2[readIndex2];  // subtract the last reading:
      readings2[readIndex2] = average;                // read from the sensor:
      total2[i] = total2[i] + readings2[readIndex2];  // add the reading to the total:

      readIndex2++;
    }
    readIndex2 = 0;
    average2[i] = (total2[i] / numReadings2);


    Serial.print("Sensor");
    Serial.print(i + 1);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(average2[i]);
    Serial.print("\t");
  }
  Serial.println(" ");


}

When I plot the reading vs temperature to see correlation, I see that there is a pretty noticeable correlation with the odd number sensors and temperature, and not so much with the even number sensors.

It is about the same for the other 4 sensors with a noticeable trend on the 3rd and 5th sensor and more random on the 2nd and 4th. Im not sure if this is hardware, wiring, or my code that is causing this strange effect.
Here is the sensor schematic and PCB layout for reference. (probe A is connected to the 2 screw hole pads and is used for the timber resistance reading. probe b is not being used, is just floating, although it is connected to the 2nd channel of the op amp and its output is connected to Ax+8 on the ardunio (Sensor 1 probe A connects to A0, probe B to A8.)


Any guidance or advice to figure this out is much appreciated.

exchange two of the Arduino pins ... A0 and A1 for example ... see if the problem stays with the pin

Probe A input is connected to a big round pad, probe B not. There the big pad is connected to GND. Is this intended?

@Jens Yes the pin headers are a connection to ground, and to the opamp channel 1, the 2 big round pads are connected to gnd and just probe A opamp channel 1.
